# Array List Unit Testing

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void testGetDoctors() {
    System.out.println("GetDoctors");
    List<Doctor> result = Operations.GetDoctors();
    assertThat(result, hasItem ("Henry"));     
}
```

I wrote this recently and I noticed that the Doctor List keeps bringing up an error . I am wondering if I should add an import for the Doctor Array List or not.

Comment: Add your code directly to your question. Which error comes up?

Comment: I don't like external images, post your code here.

Comment: Please include the error that is returned

Answer (score 1):

`Doctor` is a class, you should assert that the variable `result` has the given item.

```
assertThat(result, hasItem("Henry"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just variate you test and use ArrayList.remove(object) .
Just variating a little bit can help to understand where the issue originates.
This is just for your case.
Otherwise beware of using Java ArrayList remove() in production code, it is very inefficient.
This advice is very  useful:
[enter link description here](http://blog.bondsbiz.com/2017/03/20/arraylist-algorithm-complexity-performance-and-gotchas/)